# Is it possible to replace text from a script with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, select, replace

I want to replace "from tumblr" with just "tumblr", using CSS, if possible. I'm afraid to edit it with Notepad++ because last time I broke something and now I have a trauma.

HTML class is:

```
<option value="has(span[title^=xtumblr_'])">from tumblr</option>
```

It's from a selectable field.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: you have static content? then yeah, replace it permanently, don't let the client browser do something you can do yourself. perhaps search for `>from tumblr</option>` to replace to `>tumblr</option>`

Comment: Why? Why why why why why would you do that. Why.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, CSS has no power to distinguish individual words (though there are pseudo-elements `::first-letter` and `::first-line`), and it's difficult to reliably style the `select`, and child `option`, elements with CSS.

With JavaScript this is possible, but editing (and this time *carefully*) in any text-editor, and certainly with Notepad++, is just as (if not far more) reliable.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I know how to replace it with NotePad++. But the script gets updated regularly. Last time I fixed a script to fit my own personal preferences it was updated the other day and I couldn't run it. I can't to this day, even if I delete and redownload it from Chrome.

Comment: What 'script'? The HTML file, or a JavaScript file? If you're regularly making changes then the solution is to use a dynamic server-side solution to automate the changes (where, and if, possible) rather than hard-coding the changes every time. Either way: it remains impossible with CSS (and frankly changing the CSS every time you want to add, change or remove your `option` values is unmaintainable anyway.